# PropertyChanged is null wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, null, propertychanged

Help me please!!!

I have 3 UserControls

I select user on List Users UC listbox

Then send message from SendMessage UC to Database
when i send message to Db it must refresh my chat listBox in Correspondence UC, but problem is in my ChatWrapper.

PropertyChanged in ChatWrapper is always null, and I can't refresh my ListBox in Correspondence UC with new message

List Users:

```
    public IEnumerable<EmployeesDb> getListNames
    {
        get { return Db.Instance.EmployeesDbs.ToList(); }
    }

    static EmployeesDb m_selectedUser;
    public static EmployeesDb selectedUser
    {
        get { return m_selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                m_selectedUser = value;

            Correspondence correspondence = new Correspondence();
            correspondence.CorrespondenceChat();
        }
    }
}
```

Send Message ( I try to refresh -> SendInfo.FirstOrDefault().RefreshGUI();)

```
    public static DependencyProperty SendInfoProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SendInfo",
        typeof(IEnumerable<ChatWrapper>),
        typeof(SendMessage));
    public IEnumerable<ChatWrapper> SendInfo
    {
        get { return GetValue(SendInfoProperty) as IEnumerable<ChatWrapper>; }
        set { SetValue(SendInfoProperty, value); }
    }

    void SendMessageCommandExecute()
    {
        //...

        SendInfo.FirstOrDefault().RefreshGUI();

        //...
    }
```

ChatWrapper

```
        public class ChatWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void FirePropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

            public void RefreshGUI()
            {
                FirePropertyChanged("message");
            }

            public ChatDb chatDb { get; set; }

            public string message
            {
                get
                {
                    return (chatDb != null) ? string.Format("{0} {1}.{2} / {3} / {4}\n{5}",
                    chatDb.FromEmployeesDb.surname,
                    chatDb.FromEmployeesDb.name[0],
                    chatDb.FromEmployeesDb.middleName[0],
                    chatDb.messageDateTime,
                    chatDb.computerName,
                    chatDb.message) : null;
                }
            }
```

Correspondence

```
        //...
        public partial class Correspondence : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public static DependencyProperty GetCorrespondenceInfoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "GetCorrespondenceInfo",
            typeof(IEnumerable<ChatWrapper>),
            typeof(Correspondence),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnChanged));

            public IEnumerable<ChatWrapper> GetCorrespondenceInfo
            {
                get { return GetValue(GetCorrespondenceInfoProperty) as IEnumerable<ChatWrapper>; }
                set { SetValue(GetCorrespondenceInfoProperty, value); }
            }

            static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var me = d as Correspondence;
               me.chat = me.GetCorrespondenceInfo;
            }

            ICollectionView m_CollectionView;

            public static IEnumerable<ChatWrapper> m_chat;
            public IEnumerable<ChatWrapper> chat
            {
                get { return m_chat; }
               set
               {
                   m_chat = value;
                   if (ListUsers.selectedUser != null)
                       CorrespondenceChat();
                   FirePropertyChanged("chat");
               }
            }

            public void CorrespondenceChat()
            {
                if (m_chat == null)
                    return;
                m_CollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(m_chat);

                //...

                FirePropertyChanged("chat");
         }
```

XAML of Correspondence (refresh

```
        <Grid>
            <ListBox x:Name="correspondenceListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding chat, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Correspondence}}}" 
        Height="auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
       </Grid>
```

---

I tried to write

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

PropertyChanged is no longer null, but it's still not updated

Comment: Try to use ObservableCollection for chats

Comment: WPF _should_ be subscribing to the property when the collection of `ChatWrapper` objects is bound to the `ItemsSource` in your `ListBox` via the `chat` property. I don't think you should have to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` for the property, but I am not 100% sure so you might as well try that as recommended by the previous comment.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's impossible for anyone to know for sure what the problem is, never mind tell you how to fix it. You do have a lot of irregularities in the code you posted; it's not even clear whether the `ChatWrapper` objects you're looking at are the same as those being used in the `ListBox` (which would explain the lack of subscription to the event). Please improve the question if you want an answer.